# Nashhorn ECMAException for renderToString with invalid ReactElememt

Tags: java, reactjs, nashorn

- JDK 8
- React 0.13.1

Getting the following error when using Nashorn to render a ReactJS component

`Error: Invariant Violation: renderToString(): You must pass a valid ReactElement.`

**component.js**

```
var Controller = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (React.createElement("div",null,"Hello, World!"));
  }
});

var renderEventsComponentServer = function (eventList) {
  return React.renderToString(Controller);
};
```

**From Java**

`Object html = nashorn.invokeFunction("renderEventsComponentServer", events);`

**This however works fine**

```
var renderEventsComponentServer = function (eventList) {
  return React.renderToString(React.createElement("div",null,"Hello, World!"));
};
```

With result

`<div data-reactid=".19jt6qowty6" data-react-checksum="-706801283">Hello, World!</div>`

I'm obviously missing something fundamental about how ReactJS/Nashorns works.

These are the JS files being loaded

```
nashorn.eval(read("assets/js/react.js"));  
nashorn.eval(read("assets/js/react-dom.js"));  
nashorn.eval(read("assets/js/babel.min.js"));  
nashorn.eval(read("assets/js/axios.js"));  
nashorn.eval(read("assets/js/nashorn-polyfill.js"));  
nashorn.eval(read("assets/js/events.js"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

`return React.renderToString(React.createElement(Controller, null));`

instead of

`return React.renderToString(Controller);`

did the trick.

**component.js**

```
var Controller = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (React.createElement("div",null,"Hello, World!"));
  }
});

var renderEventsComponentServer = function (eventList) {
  return React.renderToString(React.createElement(Controller, null));
};
```

**Nugget of info:**

When I started trying to use ReactJS with Nashorn for SSR I downloaded the latest version of ReactJS which was throwing lots of errors, some deprecations that were removed altogether. I'm now using 0.13.1 which seems to be working as expected.